# How to calculate this Lebesgue integral?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,A,\mu)=(Y,B,v)=(N,M,c)$ where N is the set of natural numbers, c is the counting measure and M is the power set of N.

Define $$f(x,y)= \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  2-2^{-x}\ if\ x=y\\
                  \ -2+2^{-x} \ if \ x=y+1 \\
                  \ 0 \  otherwise
                \end{array}
              \right. $$

How to calculate $\int_N \int_Nf(m,n)dc(m)dc(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mistakenly applied Tonelli's theorem (see below). Here is the correct approach which does *not* interchange the order of integration.

\begin{align}
&\int_N \int_N f(m,n) \mathop{dc(m)} \mathop{dc(n)}\\
&= \int_N \int_N (2-2^{-m}) \cdot (\mathbf{1}_{\{m=n\}}- \mathbf{1}_{\{m=n+1\}}) \mathop{dc(m)} \mathop{dc(n)}\\
&= \sum_{n \in N} \sum_{m \in N} (2-2^{-m}) (\mathbf{1}_{\{m=n\}}- \mathbf{1}_{\{m=n+1\}})\\
&= \sum_{n \in N} (2-2^{-n}) - (2-2^{-(n-1)})\\
&= \sum_{n \in N} 2^{-n}\\
&= 1.
\end{align}

---

Incorrect attempt, which shows the failure of Tonelli's theorem to hold when conditions are not met:

\begin{align}
&\int_N \int_N f(m,n) \mathop{dc(m)} \mathop{dc(n)}\\
&= \int_N \int_N (2-2^{-m}) \cdot (\mathbf{1}_{\{m=n\}} \mathop{dc(m)} \mathop{dc(n)}
- \int_N \int_N (2-2^{-m}) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{m=n+1\}} \mathop{dc(m)} \mathop{dc(n)}\\
&= \sum_{m \in N} \sum_{n \in N} (2-2^{-m})\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{m=n\}}
- \sum_{m \in N} \sum_{n \in N} (2-2^{-m}) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{m=n+1\}}\\
&= \sum_{m\in N} (2-2^{-m}) - \sum_{m \in N} (2-2^{-m})\\
&= 0.
\end{align}

First we use Tonelli's theorem to interchange the order of integration. Then, we note that for each $m$, there is only one corresponding value of $n$ that makes the summand nonzero in each double sum: $n=m$ and $n=m+1$ respectively.

---

Thanks to user1559897 for catching my sloppy mistake.

Comment: f here is not nonnegative. So tonelli does not really apply here. In fact, this is a classic example where tonelli does not hold. Please dont remove your existing answer as the answer without interchanging the integrals should produce a different value.

Comment: @user1559897 Thanks for the catch; will fix in a second.